# matlab call scala function

Tags: matlab, scala

I would like to write some pieces of code in Scala .  It is important for me that this code can be called from matlab.  AFAIK java code can easily be integrated with matlab.  http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/javamethod.html

Is this valid also for scala code?

Answer (score 4):

It is also valid for Scala code.  Just pretend that you're doing Java interop (e.g. a method called `+` would actually be `$plus`) and make sure scala-library.jar is in Matlab's classpath (e.g. using `javaaddpath`).

Incidentally, I've done Java/Matlab interop before, and it's not as "easily integrated" as one might hope.  Passing data is kind of awkward and you tend to trip on classloader and/or classpath issues every now and then.

I'd be wary of planning a big project with lots of tightly-connected interop.  In my experience it usually works better using the Unix mindset: make independent tools that do their own thing well, and chain them together to get what you want.  For instance, I routinely have Scala write Matlab code and call Matlab to run it, or have Matlab use system to fire up a Scala program to process a subset of the data.

So--calling Scala from Matlab is completely possible, and for simple interfaces looks just like Java.  Just try to keep the interface simple.

Answer (score 0):

You could encapsulate your Scala code in another language that's easily called by Matlab, such as Java of C. Since you seem to know about Java, you could use [these examples](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~michelou/scala/using-scala-from-java.html) to learn to encapsulate your Scala methods inside Jave methods that you can call from Matlab. A number of other methods are available to you with different languages ([MEX-files](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/introducing-mex-files.html), [loadlibrary](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loadlibrary.html), etc...)